# Source Code Repository Software Choice for Storing Source Code (Not for Dev)

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, cvs

I am looking for a source code repository system with the following requirements:

We have multiple software companies across the globe building various kinds of tools for us.
The development of these tools happens via each such software companies own tools (like SVN, Mercurial, CVS etc).

What I am looking for is a versioning system to store the 'final versions' of each of these code bases for archiving purpose in a central repository. Of course, for each software's next release, the next version's final code need to be updated in this central repository.

In a crux, I am looking for a source code repository not intended for daily use (like branching, merging, etc), but just to store the final versions of various software built by various vendors of mine, with security features like role based access (one vendor must not be able to read the source code of another vendor).

Can you suggest the best open source software that will meet my requirement ? CVS ? SVN ? Mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **ANY**

Longer answer

All mentioned SCMs support linear history without problems, have sufficient ACLs. DVCS, contrary to CVCS, just doesn't require from you to have and support additional central repository-server, independent from you workplace (if it matter)